# In Laravel project, Insert update delete data code on same page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am new for Laravel coding, Actually I want to data Insert, view, Update, Delete on same. Please give some project link or code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please review this before submitting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to learn `RESTful controllers`:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Answer (score 1):

use ajax call to achieve the the operations and the corresponding api should be present at back-end.. to achieve the same you can use RESTFul Controllers or define your own.